# How to: Sliding from one background image to another 100% height and width

Tags: jquery, css, background, slider, position

Hey guys (and possibly girls!)

I'm looking for a way to slide a background image to the left and have another background image replace the first one slide in from the right.  This needs to be set up so the images can be replaced (so when you click on a page, the unique image comes in and the previous one is replaced).

I've had a good try at a few things such as the jQuery `animate` function: `animate("backgroundPosition: "-" + $(window).width() + " 0px");`

That works along very well with this plugin: http://keith-wood.name/backgroundPos.html

At the moment, I have a div tag just after the body with 100% height and width, position absolute and z-index:-1.  It works great static but I can't work out a smooth way to remove this (to the side) and at the same time have another image load from the left and slide over replacing the old one.

I've tried most things but it would be great if anyone has any ideas of how to tackle this correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using background position, why not have statically positioned backgrounds in adjacent absolute positioned `div`s?  Keep a second `div` offscreen with the background you are transitioning to, then slide both `div`s moving the original offscreen and the new one onscreen.

You can make the effect ongoing by subsequently destroying the offscreen `div`, and recreating it offscreen on the opposite side with the next background in the sequence.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea - will give this one a go.  Do you think this will work with the 'cover' environment so it will fill the screen?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure what you mean by "'cover' environment."

Comment: Where no matter how large the screen size is, the image is stretched to fit the background.

Comment: Sure--some CSS and/or JS to ensure that both the div and child images have width and height set to 100% of the viewport should suffice.